# Reducing similar commands

Tags: c#

How can I reduce the amount of similar commands into a loop?

Something like

```
pictureBox7.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
pictureBox9.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
pictureBox10.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
pictureBox11.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
pictureBox12.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
pictureBox13.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
```

Comment: "will add on later"  What?  Why would you ask a question _now_ if you intend not to provide additional details until _later_?

Comment: I was in an unexpected rush to leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PictureBox[] pbs = new PictureBox[]{ pictureBox1, pictureBox2, ...};
for(int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++) pbs[i].BackColor = Color.FromARGB(187,187,187)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var pics = new PictureBox[] {pictureBox7, 
                             pictureBox8, 
                             pictureBox9, 
                             pictureBox10, etc... };, 
pics.ToList().ForEach(p => p.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187));
```

Comment: Why create an array simply to `ToList()` it right away? Why not begin with a list from the start? `var pics = new List<PictureBox> { /* ... */ };`

Answer (score 3):

As implied by the other answers, you need to gather the controls which you want to perform the same operation on into some sort of `List`, then you can loop over it to set all controls to the same value.  A good way to do this would be to have a methods which adds the control to a private list and then another method which applies whatever operation to each control in the list.  This allows you to easily add more later without having to dig through code or do excessive amounts of copy-n-paste coding.

Once you do this you can stop naming your controls `Control##` and start giving them actual descriptive names as to what their purpose is.  Having automatically named controls in a working project is a *bad* idea, as later you'll be beating your head against the wall trying to remember what `pictureBox28` is actually for, whereas `pictureBoxPreview` has a slightly more obvious reason for existing.

Comment: I vote for calling the Control## naming convention "astigmatic naming" (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Astigmatism.aspx)

Comment: I think that naming convention is Alan Cooper's fault - he either invented it with the original Visual Basic, or else helped spread it into ubiquity through VB to Visual Interdev to Visual Studio. How much happier would we all be if Cooper had just written the VB designer to force programmers to enter a name for each control?

Comment: Having separate control objects and a method which adds those objects to a list can be useful in situations where controls are auto generated by IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

```
Color color = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is PictureBox) // don't get me started on is vs. as
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)ctrl;
        pb.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you simplify it with a call to `OfType<PictureBox>()`?

Comment: What lc said. And anyway, this would be better with as instead of is :P

Comment: Must ... fight ... urge ... to ... debate ... is ... *vs* ... as. Instead, I will respond to `lc` by saying that I would never ever write a stupid @#&$*@# function like this to iterate through pictureboxes in the first place. If I wanted to iterate through a list of pictureboxes, I would iterate through a list of pictureboxes.

Comment: Allright, I give up. Here's a little poem I just composed in honor of the `is` vs. `as` debate: "If as is better than is, why is is there at all?"

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following. Note, the syntax might not be perfect, but you get the idea.

```
foreach(var pb in new PictureBox[] {pictureBox7, pictureBox9, pictureBox10, pictureBox11, pictureBox12, pictureBox13})
    pb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 187, 187);
```